# (Dis)prove that there are 6 homomorphisms from $D_{21}$ to $D_{15}$.

Tags: group-theory

I'm having a little trouble proving how many homomorphisms there are. A function $\phi$ is an homomorphism from $D_{21}$ to $D_{15}$ if $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$. So I tried to use that each element from $D_n$ can be written as $s^ir^j$ for some $i = 1$ or $i = 0$ and $0 \leq j \leq n$. So suppose $s^ir^j$ maps to $s^kr^l$, then $\phi(s^ir^js^{i'}r^{j'}) = \phi(s^ir^{j - j'}s^{i'}) = \phi(s^{i + i'}r^{j' - j}) = \phi(s^ir^j)\phi(s^{i'}r^{i'}) = s^{k + k'}r^{l' - l}$, but I have no idea how to use this to count homomorphisms. So I'd appreciate some hints. Other prove/disprove questions from the same exam could be solved in 3 lines, so I think I'm overthinking it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** also use the relation that $r^{21}=1$. In particular, you must find  *all* elements in $a\in D_{15}$ so that $a^{21}=1$.

From this, you have to decide how to define the homomorphism. It is easiest to do this by deciding where to send generators, and checking thaat *all* relations are satisfied.

In particular, $s \mapsto \phi(s)$ must be an element of order $2$ in $D_{15}$. What are your choices here?

$\phi(r)^{21}=1$.

Once you've specified generators, such that all of the relations in the original group are satisfied, you have a (unique) homomorphism, and if you find all possible homomorphisms by using the specifications above, you will be done.

Comment: Why must $\phi(r)$ be an element of order $2$?

Comment: $f(1)=f(r^2)=f(r)f(r)$

Comment: Ah ok, my book uses $r^n = e$ and $s^2 = e$. So all elements of order 2 in $D_{15}$ are $sr^j$ for some $0 \leq j \leq 14$ and $e, r^{15}$, and a possible element we can send $r$ to is $e$ as $e^{21} = e$, so we have at least $(14 + 2)\cdot1 = 16$ homomorphisms, is that correct?

Comment: @PeldePinda excuse me, I was just writing bad variables.

Comment: @PeldePinda no. How many homomorphisms are there so that $\phi(r)=e$? Where can you send $s$?

Comment: You can send $s$ to $sr^j$ for some $0 \leq j \leq 14$ and $e, r^{15}$, and $r$ to $e$ and $r^{j}$ for $j = 0, 5, 15, 20$ as $(sr^j)^{21} = sr^j \neq e$ and $r^{21j} = e$ if and only if $21j = 0 \mod 15$ which is true for $j = 0, 5, 15, 20$. So that makes $4\cdot 16$ homomorphisms?

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry. I again mixed up the symbols, and deleted my comments. As a heads up, also consider $r \mapsto r^5$